# Specify the supertype of a class upon instantiation/declaration?

Tags: java, inheritance, oop, design-principles

Is it possible to specify the parent of a class when I instantiate/declare that class? For example, can I do something similar to this:

```
MonitoredDevice<DeviceTypeToExtend> device = null;
```

And then from that statement, the MonitoredDevice class would extend from the type parameter DeviceTypeToExtend. Now, I know that you can't use type parameters to extend from a superclass, but does anyone know of something similar to achieve this goal of "dynamically" extending from a specific parent.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Inheritance is overrated**, use composition instead (it's more powerful and flexible):

```
MonitoredDevice monitored = new MonitoredDevice();
monitor.setTargetDevice(new BaseDevice());
```

or a decorator pattern:

```
new MonitoredDeviceDecorator(new BaseDevice());
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that because then the `MonitoredDevice` class would have to extend directly from its own type parameter, which is not possible.  You could instead have something like `MonitoredDevice<T extends MonitoredDevice<T>>`, as with Enums, and then there would still be raw type information for the supertype.

Comment: Joshua Bloch discusses such *recursive type bounds* in *Effective Java*, excerpted here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/generics.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options.  It may help if you post the interfaces for MonitoredDevice & DeviceTypeToExtend, so we can get a better picture of what you're hoping to achieve.

mhaller's feedback makes sense;  you probably don't want to do it all with inheritance.

One possibility:  use generics.  Your MonitoredDevice interface might look like this:

```
public interface MonitoredDevice<E> {

  E computeFoo();

  void doBar();

}
```

You could also use composition (probably simplest) or a multi-level class hierarchy (not recommended).